# extract multiple strings with regex

Tags: awk

I have the following text:

```
Disable Automounting    /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled autofs | /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if(NR==0) print "disabled" }'
Ensure nodev option set on /home partition  for i in /etc/fstab; do /bin/echo '==========' `/bin/ls -la $i`; /bin/cat $i; done
```

I would like to get the cmd line in both line, by matching :

- what is between `/` and `}'` -> `usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled autofs | /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if(NR==0) print "disabled"`
- OR what is between `for` and `done` ->  `i in /etc/fstab; do /bin/echo '==========' /bin/ls -la $i; /bin/cat $i;`

I managed to do it with one matching group : `for(.*)done`

I can't with both though.

Thanks

Comment: Try `/.*}|for .* done`

Comment: I guess you want the entire command in the first line including the single-quote: `\/.*}'|for .* done`

Comment: @user2567674 You tagged __only__ `regex`. Are you asking about specific regex usage, or do you actually write a script? If you write a script, then tag for example `bash` or `sed` or `awk` or `linux`, depending on which script you write.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve what you want using the lookahead and lookbehind features of PCRE and since GNU grep supports PCRE (while sed and awk do not), you can use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -Po "(?<=\/)(.*?)(?= }')|(?<=for )(.*?)(?= done)" <<-'EOF'
Disable Automounting    /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled autofs | /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if(NR==0) print "disabled" }'
Ensure nodev option set on /home partition  for i in /etc/fstab; do /bin/echo '==========' `/bin/ls -la $i`; /bin/cat $i; done
EOF
```

`(?<=\/)(.*?)(?= }')` matches what's between `/` and  `}'` while `(?<=for )(.*?)(?= done)` matches what's between `for`  and  `done`. `|` between the two expressions is just the PCRE OR operator.